# Maven: my class says HttpServletRequest not found

Tags: maven, dependencies

My class complains that it couldn't find HttpServletRequest. I can google and find out what maven dependency to include in the pom file. But , is there any maven command to find out what could be the dependency to include. when we develop any maven based java application, There could be always errors like this. How to tackle them with the help of maven commands ?

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: AFAIK there is no maven command that will achieve this. This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500141/find-a-jar-file-given-the-class-name details command line scripts that you could use to search your local maven repository for all jars containing a particular class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven - How to find correct groupId/artifactId to include dependency in POM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565889/maven-how-to-find-correct-groupid-artifactid-to-include-dependency-in-pom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's such a plugin (yet). What I would do is use http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch and fill the classname. Since this searchmethod has an [API](http://search.maven.org/#api) one could wrap it with a Maven plugin.

Comment: AFAIK, no. Actually, even the hosting of Maven Central is not done by the Apache Maven team, but by Sonatype. http://search.maven.org is the most official site.