# Maven dependencies not found. How can I find them?

Tags: maven

I am using Eclipse Maven, and I created a Maven project. I need some JAR files. I tried to specify them as dependencies in my POM.XML file. I also searched for the dependencies in the Internet, but I wasn't able to get any Maven dependency information.

Maven dependency JARs I searched for are:

- wink-1.4.jar maven dependency
- commons-logging-api-1.1.3.jar
- commons-logging-adapters-1.1.3.jar

Can you please help me find these these dependency JARs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven - How to find correct groupId/artifactId to include dependency in POM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565889/maven-how-to-find-correct-groupid-artifactid-to-include-dependency-in-pom)

Answer (score 1):

Use site like http://search.maven.org/ or http://mvnrepository.com

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
    <artifactId>wink-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

All `wink` artifacts: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.wink%22

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Some artifact are not available, like `commons-logging-api-1.1.3` in repository. [Download artifact](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi) and install locally.

- [How to manually install an artifact in Maven 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442230/how-to-manually-install-an-artifact-in-maven-2)

Sample command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=commons-logging-api-1.1.3.jar -DgroupId=commons-logging -DartifactId=commons-logging-api -Dversion=1.1.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: There's also http://findjar.com/index.x, which I used back when I still drank the Java kool-aid. :)

Comment: What is specified wink-client is only about 55KB size but i need the wink-1.4 which is 1.0MB size can please send the artifact

Comment: k but what i am trying to do is specify all the dependent jars in POM.XML and i would like to generate a war file and i would like to run it in tomcat in another system if i install it as locally how the other system can access it.